# How can i use a DialogFragment in a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, android-dialogfragment

I am working on a `ListView` in my `Activity` and I need to get information from the user in DialogFragment and update it on real time basis to my `ListActivity`.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You use Dialog Fragment like this:

Your dialog fragment class:

```
public class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {

  private EditText mEditText;

  public EditNameDialog() {
      // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
    getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

    return view;
  }
```

}

In your activity class you implements EditNameDialogListener and call this function in your list item onclick event:

```
private void showEditDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EditNameDialog editNameDialog = new EditNameDialog();
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}
```

Comment: but i have a view am using listActivity for?

Comment: I dont understand your problem now. Can you explain?